# how to resolve plenty of concurrent write operation in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, concurrency, transactions, real-time

I am maintaining a lottery website with more than millions of users. Some active user(Perhaps more than 30,000) will buy more than 1000 lotteries within 1 second. 
Now the current logics use select .... for update to make sure the account balance, but meantime the database server is over-loaded and very slow to deal with? We have to process them in real-time.

Have anyone met the similar scene before?

Comment: I think you should explain more briefly.

Comment: can you quantify overloaded, you need to investigate where the bottleneck is, disk/latch contention/cpu etc, if you want a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to design a transactional system that satisfies your business rules.  For the moment, forget about disk and memory, and what goes where.  Try to design a system that is as lightweight as possible, that does the minimum required amount of locking, that satisfies your business rules.

Now, run the system, what happens?  If performance is acceptable, congratulations, you're done.

If performance is not acceptable, *avoid* the temptation to guess at the problem, and start making adjustments.  You need to profile the system.  You need to understand where the most time is being spent, so that you know what areas to focus your tuning efforts on.  The easiest way to do this, is to trace it, using SQL_TRACE.  You've not made any mention of Oracle edition, version, or platform.  So, I'll assume you're at least on some version of 10gR2.  So, use DBMS_MONITOR to start/end traces.  Now, scoping is important here.  What I mean is, it's critically important that you start the trace, run the code that you want to profile and then immediately shut off the trace.  This way, you trace only what you're interested in, and the profile won't contain any extraneous information.  Once you have the trace file, you need to process it.  There are several tools.  The most common is TkProf, which is provided by Oracle, but really doesn't do a very good job.  The best free profiler that I'm aware of, is OraSRP.  Download a copy of OraSRP, and check your results.  The data in the report should point you in the right direction.

Once you've done all that, if you still have questions, ask a new question here, and I'm sure we can help you interpret the output of OraSRP, to help you understand where your bottlenecks are.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would lock/update the accounts in memory and update the database as a background task.  Using this approach you can easily support thousands of updates and accounts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the data is very important, you know the table contains users accounts with money. So users wanna check their account in real-time.

Comment: If the accounts are in memory, your checks will be in real time.  The main problem is ensuring the information is not lost on a failure.  Most real disks only support 100 IOPS per second.  You will have to cache the data at some level to support this update rate. Using SSDs might be all you need as it can support more IOPS per second.

Answer (score 2):

**A. Speed up things without modifying the code:**

1 - You can keep the table entirely in the memory(that is SGA - because it is also on disks):

```
    alter table t storage ( buffer_pool keep )
```

(discuss with your dba before to do this)

2 - if the table is too big and you update same rows again and again, probably it is sufficient to use the cache attribute:

```
    alter table t cache
```

This command put the blocks of your table when they are used with best priority in the LRU list, so it is less chance to be aged from the SGA.
Here is it a discusion about differences: [ask tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:253415112676)

3 - Another solution, advanced, that need more analysis and resources is [TimesTen](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/imdb-cache/index.html)

**B.Speed up your database operations:**

Identify top querys and:

- create indexes where you update or select only one row or a small set of rows.
- partition large tables scanned for only a segment of data.

Have you identified a top query?

Comment: Thanks Bro, 
1. I wanna make sure whether the in the memory db will  ensure the business transaction data reliability and consistence or not?
2. How to synch data from memory db to disk db? should I make some changes with the current logics?

Comment: keeping the table entirely in SGA does not need anything to be done in code, nothing like sincronyze, refresh and other stuff. For programmer it absolutely transparent. Oracle will ensure that all data is safe on disks. And keep this in mind: when you query a DML, allways Oracle modifies data in memory(SGA) and other oracle processes writes that data on disks. In our case, nothing is different form this point of view.

Comment: you just need to discuss with you DBA to be sure that it is enough space in SGA, and any other dba related stuff.

Comment: Assigning tables to the keep buffer pool is really something the DBA should be doing, because the size of the keep pool may need to be adjusted as well.  As to the 'cache' attribute, I don't think this does what you think it does.  If a table is set to 'cache', the only thing that changes is the behavior of blocks on the LRU *when a full table scan operation happens*!  The 'cache' attribute will make NO difference, if you're only accessing the table's blocks via an index!

Comment: I said that it is a must to discuss with the DBA the keep buffer pool ideea, I don't understand your complain. And the cash attribute was recomended with "IF". And if the block is in memory the dates will come faster even you acces them via index because you still need to read the table block(it doesn't make a difference only if the queryed column is indexed).